# How to create a manifest file for a C++ project? [for DPI awareness]

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to add **DPI awareness per monitor v2** to a C++ application, using VS2022. Microsoft recommends to do this using the application manifest. So far I have been using an automatically generated intermediate manifest file (using the setting under linker -> generate manifest: yes). However, this file is not actually generated in the filing system (the location where it is purported to be does not contain the desired manifest file). Because it is not being generated, I have no example manifest that I can modify to suit my needs.

Various other answers on Stackoverflow all indicate that you can generate a manifest file if you have the C# compiler installed, which I do not. The C++ compiler has no option for creating a manifest file.

Lacking both a wizard and an example file, what other options do I have for setting up a manifest file containing all required information?

Comment: In this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process) from Microsoft documentation there's an example of manifest file and also some suggetions on how to implement in code

Comment: You could tell Visual Studio to generate a manifest file for a particular project in the project's Property Pages dialog. For details I suggest you to read this [issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/build/understanding-manifest-generation-for-c-cpp-programs.md).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the manifest is embedded into the compiled application (exe or dll). You can access it with a resource viewer. There is an option to control that in Manifest Tool -> Input and Output -> Embed Manifest.

All manifest files included in your project are merged and added to the application manifest (maybe the file type also need to be set as Manifest file for it to work)

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realise manifest files would be merged together. This means I don't have to specify a complete manifest file, I can just leave the automatically generated file turned on and add the one section I actually need as a separate file. This fixes the problem for me.